# Conditional Formatting: if the value matches one of these

Tags: conditionals

I'm using a multi-author field (VZ Members) that outputs this for author IDs;

```
4333|3871|3957
```

How can I show entries that match the logged in user?  Something like:

```
If logged_in_member_id matches one of these, 4333|3871|3957, then show entry.
```

Is there a built-in EE way or does this jump to embedded php?  (I hope this question isn't too trivial... it feels that way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a normal conditional to work you would have to write it like this:

```
{if logged_in_member_id == "4333" || logged_in_member_id == "3871"}
```

However that's not very flexible and isn't going to work with a piped list of IDs. I've written a custom plugin in the past to solve a similar issue. There's a plugin called [Pvl Check If](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pvl-check-if) on Devot:ee that I think would work in this situation. Your code using the plugin would look something like this:

```
{exp:pvl_checkif value="{logged_in_member_id}" is_in="{members_field}{id}|{/members_field}" parse="inward"}
    <p>Yes Sir!</p>
{else}
    <p>No Sir!</p>
{/exp:pvl_checkif}
```

I'm not sure how the variable pair will go inside the plugin parameter... you may need to play around with it a bit. Perhaps try with hardcoded values first.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do `{if logged_in_member_id == "4333|3871|3957"}`.

Or with VZ Members, which I'm not familiar with, it should be `{if logged_in_member_id == "{members_field}{id}|{/members_field}"}`

Comment: That's what I thought too, and it works if one author is selected, but not two or more.

Comment: Hmm. I'm guessing creating member groups is not going to help your case?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  They are already in member groups and this would be to give access on a per-entry basis, like an override to the member group.  ...and there's going to be a whole lot of entries.

Comment: Does the `{members_field}` tag pair inside of a preload variable work? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/preload_replacement.html

Comment: It passes, but does not solve the problem.

Comment: What ee version u have? As I remember right in_group condition works starting from 2.5.2